# What does it mean by "The continuous date / time input field 'u_busq_idig' is ignored. Insufficient type specified for field 'sex'"?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

i´m creating a model and at the moment of using de C5.0 Operator is appears me error and the following message: "The continuous date / time input field 'u_busq_idig' is ignored.

Insufficient type specified for field 'sex'"

Here i leave the image.

Thank you in advance! [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please tag the programming language/framework/tool that you are using. I am unable to tell what it is. Most likely you also need to provide a [repro] and the full original error message in English (change language setting if necessary).

Comment: Hi, i´m using IBM Watson Studio. Secondly, i don´t know how to provide a minimal repoducible example, i don´t find the code to copy. And the laguage setting i can´t change it, maybe is because is a trail demo that i´m using.

Answer (score 0):

@Cristobal Daponte, C5.0 does not use any field with type `Time`, `Date` and `Timestamp` to build model, if any field with these type are used as input field, it will automatically skip them and report the warning message you saw.
For the error, you might need to add a `Type` node before the modeling node, and initialize all input fields by click the `Read Values` button in the node editor like below:

[Read Values in Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oebEL.png)